# Experience with many radiobuttons and jquery ui buttonset?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Does somebody have experience with using many groups of radiobuttons and the jquery-ui buttonset() method? I have run into trouble with poor performance in IE7/8 when creating many radiobuttons like 300.

best regards

pmla

Comment: Do you mean *three hundred radio buttons* in the same buttonset?

Comment: yeah more or less. i have a page used to upload files. when uploading a file the user must assign read or write access rights for other users to the file. in the same page there is also a edit document form for editing access rights. so if there are like 100 users that makes 100x2(for read radio and write radio)x2(two forms)400 radiobuttons in two set. i know this is bad design because userlist may increase.

Comment: How is the user supposed to pick the person out of that list of 100? CTRL+F in the browser?! How about a better UI, like a combobox or auto-completing text box that lets you pick a user? I think the browser is so slow because it's weeping over this poor UI design.

Comment: @pmla, if you know that's bad design, *why are you trying to implement it*?

Comment: well yeah its implemented, and now im trying to fix it. sometimes you just make bad decisions when working with little time, and im not that experienced.however the thing i was wondering about was that ie7 and ie8 used much more time than firefox in initializing jquery ui buttons? but maybe its just my code. but thanks for the ui tips

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same thing with IE7 and 10 button sets. I think I've tracked it down to this bug. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5454